# Fullcalendar event cell background color

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using Fullcalendar with a Google Calendar so I can't apply a class to an event as far as I'm aware.

What I want to do should be quite simple and I'm sure the answer will involve eventRender but I just can't get it working.

Simply: change the entire background color of the cell that contains any event (all events are "all day" within the Google Calendar).

What I'm trying to achieve is an "availability" state; any event is "unavailable" i.e. background color red.

Comment: Tried using [eventColor](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventColor/)? "This option can be overridden on a per-source basis with the color Event Source Object option or on a per-event basis with the color Event Object option."

Comment: @RichardHermanson I believe he means the entire cell, not just the event data.

Comment: Also, in the future, including some code that shows your attempt helps.

Comment: A screenshot would be helpful to describe what you're looking to create here.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you can do it with `eventRender`. You'll have to find the `td` that contains that event. If you inspect the fullCalendar, you'll note the `tds` have a `data-date` attribute for that particular day. That is how we will find the `td` that has an event in it so we can change the background color to red, specifically using:

```
eventRender: function (event, element) {
    var dataToFind = moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    $("td[data-date='"+dataToFind+"']").addClass('activeDay');
}
```

In this example, the first line in `eventRender` uses moment to format the event start date into the format needed to match the `data-date` attribute value. The second line finds a `td` with the `data-date` attribute having a value of `dataToFind` and then adds a class we make up called `activeDay`, assuming you add something like this to your head/stylesheet:

```
<style>
    .activeDay {background-color:#ff0000 !important;}
</style>
```

```js
$('#fullCal').fullCalendar({
  events: [{
    title: 'Main Event 1',
    start: new Date(),
    end: new Date(),
    allDay: false
  }, {
    title: 'Main Event 2',
    start: '2014-10-03 19:00',
    end: '2014-10-03 19:30',
    allDay: false
  }, {
    title: 'Main Event 3',
    start: '2014-10-15 17:00',
    end: '2014-10-15 18:00',
    allDay: false
  }, {
    title: 'Main Event 4',
    start: '2014-11-30 7:00',
    end: '2014-11-30 18:00',
    allDay: false
  }, ],

  header: {
    left: '',
    center: 'prev title next',
    right: ''
  },
  eventRender: function(event, element) {
    var dataToFind = moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    $("td[data-date='" + dataToFind + "']").addClass('activeDay');
  }
});
```

```css
.activeDay {
  background-color: #ff0000 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.1.1/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.1.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

<p>Example:</p>
<div id="fullCal"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @MikeSmithDev does not work if you have events on multiple days.

If you have multiple days use this javascript:

```
eventRender: function (event, element) {
    var start = moment(event.start);
    var end = moment(event.end);
    while( start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') != end.format('YYYY-MM-DD') ){
        var dataToFind = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        $("td[data-date='"+dataToFind+"']").addClass('dayWithEvent');
        start.add(1, 'd');
    }

}
```

It uses the same principle as MikeSmithDev's, so you must use the same css.