# fullCalendar hide event titles, but set cell/day background

Tags: fullcalendar

Using:

```
* FullCalendar 2.1.1
* month view
```

I would like to display a mini calendar - all it shows is the day of the month - no event titles. 
But, on days that have events - i would like that cell to have a background color. (Sample below)

I guess via CSS i can manually hide all events using `.fc-event-container {display: none;}`
but what code would i use to change the cell background, if an event exists? something for `dayRender`?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26681896/fullcalendar-event-cell-background-color

Comment: kinda. i saw that. there they are looking for a specific event/date. What i am stuck on, is how to check if a date has an event in it.

Comment: Just go through all the events and check what events they are on..

Comment: got it! - pls answer this as the answer, and i will check it off.

Comment: Meant "what day they are on". Try it yourself first, if you're still having trouble post your attempt here and I'll help you

Comment: no, i meant that you were right. i got the answer based on your suggestion. i would like to you off as the correct answer

Comment: Gj. Post your solution instead, i didn't do anything :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With thanks to @Richard Hermanson, this is how to solve the issue

First we use this `eventRender` function to locate all events that start on a specific day, then we apply a class to the cell with that date.

```
eventRender: function (event, element) {
    var dataToFind = moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    $("td[data-date='"+dataToFind+"']").addClass('dayWithEvent');
}
```

Now, we use this CSS, to hide the event titles, and to highlight the day cells -

```
.dayWithEvent { background: #AB6D86; cursor: pointer;}
.fc-event-container {display: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @Kniedels does not work if you have events on multiple days.

If you have multiple days use this javascript:

```
eventRender: function (event, element) {
    var start = moment(event.start);
    var end = moment(event.end);
    while( start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') != end.format('YYYY-MM-DD') ){
        var dataToFind = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        $("td[data-date='"+dataToFind+"']").addClass('dayWithEvent');
        start.add(1, 'd');
    }

}
```

It uses the same principle as Kniedels', so you must use the same css.