# FullCalendar DayRender

Tags: fullcalendar

I am trying to change the background color of a day that has an event or specific days. The key here is the color of the day and not the event. Actually, It doesn't matter if the event displays or not so I can either create the days that I need as events or just pass the dates directly to the dayrender. I am not a JS coder by any stretch of the imagination so a full sample would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Richard, the linked solution worked. Thanks!!

[Fullcalendar event cell background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26681896/fullcalendar-event-cell-background-color)