# (fullcalendar) Passing calendar background color in event object with start/stop time

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar and I am looking for a way to pass background color as an event
so that my calendar app can use a combination of colored events and colored backgrounds.
I'm pretty sure this is not supported by the library, so if anyone has any notes towards coding the feature or experience working with the code, that would be helpful.

[image]

The following question is very similar to mine, but not written clearly enough to know if it's a dupe:
[Fullcalendar event cell background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26681896/fullcalendar-event-cell-background-color)

**Update 1**

Based on the accepted answer, I use the following event specs

```
{
    title: '',
    start: moment().add(2,'h').toISOString(),
    end: moment().add(5,'h').toISOString(),
    color: 'rgba(63, 191, 191, 0.24)',
    textColor: 'rgba(63, 191, 191, 0)',
    editable: false,
    durationEditable: false,
    allDay: false,
    fakeEvent: true
},          
{
    title: 'WORK DAY',
    start: moment().add(1,'h').toISOString(),
       end: moment().add(3,'h').toISOString(),
       color: 'green',
    //background-color = 'blue'                     
},
```

And get this result. Next step is trying to prevent the event overlapping display algorithm, so that the light blue appears more like a background color, less like an event.

[image]

**Update 2**

I have since discovered this example app that accomplishes what I needed: http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.2.0/demos/background-events.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That question you referenced isn't the same. He was looking to change the background color of any day that has an event, not the event itself. What you are trying to do is supported by the library. You can set the color of the event by passing in a `color` property with the event data.

All examples can be found on the [FullCalendar Event Source Object](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Source_Object/) page. As noted on that example page, you can set it in the array of events:

```
{
    events: [
        {
            title: 'Event1',
            start: '2011-04-04'
        },
        {
            title: 'Event2',
            start: '2011-05-05'
        }
        // etc...
    ],
    eventColor: 'yellow',   // an option!
    textColor: 'black' // an option!
}
```

or in JSON:

```
{
    url: '/myfeed.php',
    color: 'yellow',   // an option!
    textColor: 'black' // an option!
}
```

Now, those are setting the background for every event in the source, but you can do it per event as well, the same way, like:

```
[
    {
        "title": "Free Pizza",
        "allday": "false",
        "borderColor": "#5173DA",
        "color": "#99ABEA",
        "textColor": "#000000",
        "description": "Fake description for the Free Pizza",
        "start": "2014-11-15T16:30:28",
        "end": "2014-11-15T17:30:28",
        "url": "some url"
    },
    {
        "title": "CSS Meetup",
        "allday": "false",
        "borderColor": "#820F20",
        "color": "#A6113C",
        "textColor": "#ffffff",
        "description": "Fake description",
        "start": "2014-11-19T16:30:28",
        "end": "2014-11-19T18:30:28",
        "url": "someUrl
    }
]
```

You can use `eventColor` and `eventTextColor` ([src](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventColor/)) to set the background for *all* events on the calendar, like

```
$('#fullCal').fullCalendar({
    events: [...],
    eventColor: 'yellow',
    eventTextColor: 'black'
});
```

After further clarification it appears you want certain time slots to have colors but not be a "real" event. You can do this in FullCalendar 2.2 using the `Background Events` by adding `rendering: 'background'` to the event ([documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/Background_Events/)).

```js
$('#fullCal').fullCalendar({
  events: [{
    title: 'Main Event 1',
    start: moment().add(-4, 'h'),
    end: moment().add(-2, 'h'),
    color: '#ff0000',
    allDay: false
  }, {
    start: moment().add(2, 'h'),
    end: moment().add(5, 'h'),
    rendering: 'background'
  }, {
    title: 'Main Event 2',
    start: moment().add(5, 'h'),
    end: moment().add(7, 'h'),
    color: '#00cc00',
    allDay: false,
    fakeEvent: false
  }],
  header: {
    left: '',
    center: 'prev title next',
    right: ''
  },
  timezone: 'local',
  defaultView: 'agendaWeek'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

<div id="fullCal"></div>
```

Comment: The `color` property is the color of the object that hovers over the calendar (green and red in my example). I want to color the background of the calendar itself (the beige), so that I can have colored backgrounds AND colored events.

Comment: Are you asking how to set the background color of the calendar?

Comment: yes, but i want to be able to specify start and stop times over which the background color would apply. So that the calendar can show a range of colors.

Comment: OK I think I understand. Maybe create an event for that time slot with and a different `color`? Would that work? If you don't want to display times/titles for it you can manage in the `eventRender`.

Comment: @ted.strauss added an example to show how to add a color time slot... which is what I think you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: it's still the same question, but your answer has shown some limits of what the library can do, and pointed me in the right direction. So I'll just leave it at that for now.

Comment: @ted.strauss it looks like this functionality exists now in version 2.2. I updated my answer. See if that works for you! Much less hacky than what I had before.

Comment: holy molé that version is just a few days old. the developer read my mind.

Comment: @ted.strauss yeah, that is what I was thinking. I just happened to stumble on it and said hey... looks familiar. Kinda glad it didn't exist before because it would've made my original answer such a stupid workaround... ha!