# Fullcalendar: add event sources

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have a jquery full calendar embedded in my project. I am providing event sources via a loop eg:

```
for (i = 0; i < $scope.gcalIntervieweEvents.length; i++) {
         $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', $scope.gcalIntervieweEvents[i]);
}
```

How do I provide different background colors for different event sources?

Comment: I show how to change event background color per source and per event in [this recent SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26934653/1810243).

Answer (score 0):

Check the link :- [FullCalendar Events](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
You can give backgroundColor, textColor, or borderColor to the event object.

```
events: [{
  title  : 'event1',
  backgroundColor: //As per requirement
}]
```