# fullCalendar V2 background events title

Tags: fullcalendar

I've been using the new background events in fullCalendar V2 to show which slots are available to book into but I'd like to also show a title of some kind in the background event. Setting 'title' on the event doesn't show anything.

Is there anyway of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Setting 'title' should be enough. Could you provide a plunker, jsfiddle or at least an image?

Comment: Hi Mario, by background events I mean this: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/Background_Events/

Comment: @jimbodeni at that point, why not just make it an event? Before the background events feature was available, I show a workaround in http://stackoverflow.com/a/26934653/1810243. You'll need to check the edit history. Look at code snippet in [revision 3](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26934653/revisions) (I replaced that answer after background events became available).

Answer (score 10):

I've modified the calendar's "eventRender" so that if an event detects a background rendering, also show the title:

```
eventRender: function (event, element) {
    if (event.rendering == 'background') {
        element.append(event.title);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use this code. try it.

```
eventRender: function(event, element){
    if(event.source.rendering == 'background'){
        element.append("YOUR HTML CODE");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I have recently had similar problem. I am building myself a simple webapp for managing my work time and I wanted to use fullcalendar and display how much hours I have worked on each day. Standard events where showing thin rectangle which didn't look good. I noticed that there are background events so I used them to mark on which day I worked. It looked much better as the entire day was highlighted. But similar to you I wanted to show some info, namely hours for the day. So I come up with the following solution. I create two events for the day. First one is creating a background event and second one is creating normal event with title set to hours but with background set to transparent. With a little bit help of css I align text for the standard event. The code for it looks like this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            eventBackgroundColor: '#ABFFA6',
            eventColor: 'transparent',
            eventBorderColor: 'transparent',
            eventTextColor: '#000',
            events: [
                {"start":"2015-01-02","rendering":"background"},
                {"title":"06:10","start":"2015-01-02","backgroundColor":"transparent"},
            ]
        });
```

This code will mark Jan 2nd with light green background and add 6:10 label into it. This solution can be extrapolated to other views (like day view).