# Color fullcalendarjs cells before calendar loads

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I m getting some dates from the database which are of interest to the user

(they are then dates where the user is going to take days off in the future or has taken days off in the past from his or hers job).

I have the dates in the database and i need to retrive them for each cell and color the calendarjs cells in red.

Im currently using ASP.NET MVC but i can handle any examples in any languages on how to pre-render fullcalendarjs cells.

Im more interested in how to handle the frontend.I dont need "events" i need to make the entire day cell red, the top part aka the th and the bottom part of the cell aka the td.

Comment: You could do something like I show [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26685585/1810243).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very easy, use firebug and you'll see that there is an fc-bg class used to mark the calendar squares area and each cell is marked with data-date="YYYY-MM-DD".

So you can use jQuery to find each cell and change its style.

```
$('*[data-date="'+ dateVar + '"]').addClass('some-class');
```

you can even check what other classes are set to see if its in the past, what day of the week it is, etc.
get Firebug :)