# Fullcalendar. Highlight cell background of event

Tags: jquery, css, fullcalendar

I'm passing events array to FullCalendar and it's working fine. But how can I highlight cell background basing on event title?
Currently I'm trying to use following options:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> GetQuota(string fromtype, string fromcode, string totype, string tocode, string airservice)
        {
            byte[] stream = HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode(Request.Cookies["psw"].Value);
            byte[] decodedValue = MachineKey.Unprotect(stream, "all");
            var psw = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decodedValue);
            var q = await _qr.GetQuota(User.Identity.Name, psw);
            var c = new List<Calendar>();
            foreach (var d in q.QuoteItems.Where(x => x.Quote != "none"))
            {
                c.Add(new Calendar()
                {
                    title = d.Quote,
                    start = String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", d.Date.Substring(0, 4), d.Date.Substring(4, 2), d.Date.Substring(6, 2)),
                    end = String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", d.Date.Substring(0, 4), d.Date.Substring(4, 2), d.Date.Substring(6, 2)),
                    backgroundColor = "#ff0000"
                });
            }
            return Json(c, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

But this return events without needed formatting.

Comment: To expand on Franky's answer, here is how to change the cell background: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26685585/1810243

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try docs for this [Click here for more details](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/)

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
    if(event.title == 'xyz') {
       //implement your logic here
    }
}
```

In case of month view the cells have an data-date attr you can get date from event.start format it and compare your criteria.